# How can I make a h1 header more responsive on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website: `https://acanhs.org` the site looks awesome but this happens on mobile.[image]

The text box header takes up most of the space. What can I do to fix this?

This is my html:

```
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <img src="logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag">
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="boyshome.html">Boys Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="girlshome.html">Girls Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="calculator.html">GPA Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <br>
    <div class="w3-content w3-section responsive">

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/81463156_472179973704673_8295529433598935850_n(1).jpg')" >
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/097f1e08-ebfe-434a-bc68-8020d02cee6e.JPG')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/8291878a-b5ad-4003-8cc6-de7baafd84a0.JPG')">
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/27890996_211176766129569_6923967286697000960_n.jpg')">
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/42914143_364663130939605_1259772328364992140_n.jpg')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/42947322_373232869884042_7326776160519321694_n.jpg')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/44689929_944494762409958_8911408401400786089_n.jpg')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/fd2b6c09-19b7-42ad-b7fb-bce6dc983690.JPG')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/IMG_6922.jpg')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/IMG_6932.jpg')" >
        </div>


    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
    <style>.sameborder
        {
            background-color:#F0E68C;
            width: 1200px;
            border: 10px solid;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }</style>
    <center>
    <div class="sameborder">
        <h1 class="Welcome responsive">Welcome To The National </h1>
        <h1 class="Welcome responsive">Honor Society Website!</h1>
        
    </div>
    </header>
    <br>
    </center>
    <h3 class="message" style="margin-left: 20px;">Our Message</h3>
    <h3 id="messagetext" align="justify" class="wiki-content">&emsp;&emsp;"Long before National Honor Society was available in the American Creativity Academy, students sought after an opportunity to create, inspire, and open the doors for creativity. With a heritage of respect to individuality and personal interest, the National Honor Society offered a platform for creation and student ingenuity. Today, the dream of a boy and a girl who grew between the walls of ACA turned into reality: they can finally create and enjoy creation for a respected audience!</h3>
    <h3 id="messagetext" align="justify" class="wiki-content">&emsp;&emsp;The National Honor Society is a community by students within the campus that works towards creating a better school and local environment. We believe that every act of kindness, no matter how insignificant it may seem, has a drastic impact on a person and starts a ripple of kind-hearted acts among the people. The NHS creates opportunities for its members in volunteering within and off the campus and raising awareness for global issues, which makes them more productive, responsible, and engaged citizens. We try to make a difference by inspiring and supporting the people around us whenever we can.</h3>
    <h3 id="messagetext" align="justify" class="wiki-content">&emsp;&emsp;The NHS team is more than all of its members; although the impact of one person is limited, working as a team allows us to achieve our goal and leave behind a great mark. We envision a kinder society where people are keen on helping others, and will work until that vision is achieved."</p>
    <h3 id="messagetext" align="justify" class="wiki-content">- By the NHS Team</h3>
```

What can I do to make the header fit in the screen and not force the user to zoom out to view the text?...........................................................................................................

Comment: You can make the heading responsive using `viewport width` or `media query`.
Follow this article - [Responsive Text](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like setting the `.sameborder` width to 1200px is causing the issue. A suggestion would be to make it a percentage instead (maybe width: 80%).

Answer (score 0):

Just Add This in Css:

```
.same border h1{

font-size: 2vh; /* Can change value as per your choice..  */

/*  That's It! */

}
```

I guess That will work..

Comment: will not work. the issue is the width of 1200px. No matter how small you make the font-size. the box will stay at 1200px width and therefor blow the mobile screens width.

Comment: Ohhh.................

Answer (score 0):

You did not precise but I guess the problem is not really the size of the text but more like the width of your title. So I propose you to manage it this way:

- Add a classe to `center` to set `width: 100%;` on it
- Set your class `sameborder`as below:

```
    .sameborder-container{
      width: 100%;
    }
    .sameborder{
      background-color:#F0E68C;
      max-width: 1200px;
      width: 100%;
      border: 10px solid;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 2vw;
    }
```

### DEMO:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.sameborder-container{
  width: 100%;
}
.sameborder{
  background-color:#F0E68C;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <img src="logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag">
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="boyshome.html">Boys Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="girlshome.html">Girls Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="calculator.html">GPA Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <br>
    <div class="w3-content w3-section responsive">

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/81463156_472179973704673_8295529433598935850_n(1).jpg')" >
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/097f1e08-ebfe-434a-bc68-8020d02cee6e.JPG')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/8291878a-b5ad-4003-8cc6-de7baafd84a0.JPG')">
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/27890996_211176766129569_6923967286697000960_n.jpg')">
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/42914143_364663130939605_1259772328364992140_n.jpg')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/42947322_373232869884042_7326776160519321694_n.jpg')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/44689929_944494762409958_8911408401400786089_n.jpg')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/fd2b6c09-19b7-42ad-b7fb-bce6dc983690.JPG')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/IMG_6922.jpg')">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-bottom responsive" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/IMG_6932.jpg')" >
        </div>


    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
  <center class="sameborder-container">
    <div class="sameborder">
        <h1 class="Welcome responsive">Welcome To The National </h1>
        <h1 class="Welcome responsive">Honor Society Website!</h1>
        
    </div>
  <!--</header>-->
    <br>
  </center>
    <h3 class="message" style="margin-left: 20px;">Our Message</h3>
    <h3 id="messagetext" align="justify" class="wiki-content">&emsp;&emsp;"Long before National Honor Society was available in the American Creativity Academy, students sought after an opportunity to create, inspire, and open the doors for creativity. With a heritage of respect to individuality and personal interest, the National Honor Society offered a platform for creation and student ingenuity. Today, the dream of a boy and a girl who grew between the walls of ACA turned into reality: they can finally create and enjoy creation for a respected audience!</h3>
    <h3 id="messagetext" align="justify" class="wiki-content">&emsp;&emsp;The National Honor Society is a community by students within the campus that works towards creating a better school and local environment. We believe that every act of kindness, no matter how insignificant it may seem, has a drastic impact on a person and starts a ripple of kind-hearted acts among the people. The NHS creates opportunities for its members in volunteering within and off the campus and raising awareness for global issues, which makes them more productive, responsible, and engaged citizens. We try to make a difference by inspiring and supporting the people around us whenever we can.</h3>
    <h3 id="messagetext" align="justify" class="wiki-content">&emsp;&emsp;The NHS team is more than all of its members; although the impact of one person is limited, working as a team allows us to achieve our goal and leave behind a great mark. We envision a kinder society where people are keen on helping others, and will work until that vision is achieved."</p>
    <h3 id="messagetext" align="justify" class="wiki-content">- By the NHS Team</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSS styles you're literally specifying you want the sameborder class to be this pixel-width. (1200px)

Instead you can try to set it accordingly to the device's width. You can do it with percentage, like this:

```
.sameborder
        {
            background-color:#F0E68C;
            
            /* width: 1200px; */
            /* try this one: */
            
            width: 90%; 
            
            /* You will see if it fits 
            the screen or maybe you should do 
            less percentage*/
            
            border: 10px solid;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
```